# Selected item doesn't change in QListView

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am trying to implement the functionality of an item in QListView that goes up and down when I click 'Up' and 'Down' buttons. I want that the selected item change to the new position, so you can press 'Up' button again without having to selected manually the item previously changed. But this select another item.

The code is the following:

```
def move_item(self, index_modification: int) -> None:

    max_row = self.model.rowCount()
    indexes = self.list_priority.selectedIndexes()
    if len(indexes) > 0:

        indexes.sort()
        first_row = indexes[0].row() + index_modification
        last_row = indexes[-1].row() + index_modification
        if (first_row >= 0 and index_modification == - 1) or (last_row < max_row and index_modification == 1):
            for index in indexes:
                if index is not None:
                    name = index.data()
                    row = index.row()
                    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
                    self.model.removeRow(row)
                    self.model.insertRow(row+index_modification, item)
                    pre_idx = self.model.index(0, row-1)
                    self.list_priority.selectionModel().select(pre_idx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
```

- What am I doing wrong?
- How can I fix it?

Comment: please provide a [MrE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you've got a sample code snippet. It is using `QListWidget` instead of `QListView` for simplicity reasons.
In the example `QListWidget` is inherited and the Key Press Events are handled according to your idea.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication,QListWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeyEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QEvent,QCoreApplication

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.list_priority=MyList()
        for i in ['one','two','three','four']:
            self.list_priority.addItem(i)        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.list_priority)
        

class MyList(QListWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        self.installEventFilter(self)
        
    def eventFilter(self,obj,event):
        if event.type()==QEvent.KeyPress:
            
            if (event.key()==Qt.Key_Up) or (event.key()==Qt.Key_Down) :    
                row=self.currentRow()
                item=self.takeItem(row)
                newrow = row-1 if event.key()==Qt.Key_Up else row+1
                self.insertItem(newrow,item)
                self.setCurrentItem(item)
                return True
        return False
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if QCoreApplication.instance() != None:
        app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    else:
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    prog = MainWindow()
    prog.show()
    
    app.exec_()
```